# Public Key RSA Decryption (C#)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key

My problem is the following:

I am receiving an encrypted string with RSA private key. I have the public key to decrypt it and the next method (based on suggestions such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET
and msdn):

```
public static string DecryptString(string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString){
    try
    {               
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwKeySize);
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(xmlString);

        int base64BlockSize = ((dwKeySize / 8) % 3 != 0) ?
          (((dwKeySize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((dwKeySize / 8) / 3) * 4;
        int iterations = inputString.Length / base64BlockSize;
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));
            Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);                    
            arrayList.AddRange(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false));
        }
        return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(arrayList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.Byte")) as byte[]);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());                
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

When you run I use the following values:

inputString = `g/h/UizCowOX/uQubCZ1 .... I1k2FaCMSOpkYcTOQ==` encryption string 344 chars.

dwKeySize = `2048`

xmlString = `<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>mxBSd9ss/OmV ... D8miCOWclUJdbWw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>` with the public key in xml format.

Get the following error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key does not exist.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey,Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb,Boolean fOAEP)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.DecryptString(String inputString, Int32 dwKeySize, String xmlString)
```

If I call rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt with the last parameter to TRUE the message is:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb,Boolean fOAEP)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.DecryptString(String inputString, Int32 dwKeySize, String xmlString)
```

I tried to load the public key replacing the first lines (instantiation provider) by:

```
X509Certificate2 Cert;
Cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\seggar.der"); 
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
rsaCryptoServiceProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Cert.PublicKey.Key;
```

But the same errors occur.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you actually need to decrypt with the public key?  Or do you need to verify with the public key?  What is the information you are decrypting?  This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You need a private key for decryption... You can do encryption and signature verification with public key only.

Comment: @vojta really cann't decrypt with the public key? I have tested this code in java (when "key" is the public key"):               final byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(text);
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(bytes);      and it works .. but I need to do it in C #.

Comment: @LukePark yes, I need decrypt "inputString" (mentioned in post) with the public key in "xmlString" (too mentioned in post)